# Why is NavigationService.Navigate running at the end only?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

As you can see, I want to navigate to "ScoreInputDialog.xaml" page, where the user can type in a name. After this I am trying to save the name to a list, but it is always empty because navigation to page "ScoreInputDialog.xaml" is being done at last. How can I navigate to the desired page and get my value before continuing with rest of the code?

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/ScoreInputDialog.xaml", UriKind.Relative)); // Sets tempPlayerName through a textbox.
if (phoneAppService.State.ContainsKey("tmpPlayerName"))
{
    object pName;
    if (phoneAppService.State.TryGetValue("tmpPlayerName", out pName))
    {
        tempPlayerName = (string)pName;
    }
}
highScorePlayerList.Add(tempPlayerName);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do nothing directly after the `Navigate` call. Instead override the `OnNavigatedTo` method of the page you are coming from, to get notified when the user *comes back*:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
```

This method will be called when the user exits the "ScoreInputDialog.xaml", probably by pressing the back button or because you call `NavigationService.GoBack()`. This exits the "ScoreInputDialog.xaml" page and goes to the previous page, where the `OnNavigatedTo` will be called. This is the time to check for the value.

Illustration of the navigation flow:

"OriginPage" ---[`Navigate`]---> "ScoreInputDialog" ---[`GoBack()` or Back-button]---> "OriginPage" (*)

Where the (*) is there the `OnNavigatedTo` will be called. The implementation could look like this:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (phoneAppService.State.ContainsKey("tmpPlayerName"))
    {
        object pName;
        if (phoneAppService.State.TryGetValue("tmpPlayerName", out pName))
        {
            tempPlayerName = (string)pName;
        }
        highScorePlayerList.Add(tempPlayerName);
    }
}
```

Remember to clear the temp player name before calling `Navigate`:

```
phoneAppService.State.Remove("tmpPlayerName");
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/ScoreInputDialog.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

Note: `OnNavigatedTo` will also be called when the user sees the page the first time or navigates back from other pages than "ScoreInputDialog.xaml". But then the "tmpPlayerName" value will not be set.

Comment: Thanks for the example and explanation. It solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

`Navigate` isn't being performed last, it is just happening asynchronously.  You have to wait for the navigation to complete.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.navigated.aspx

Comment: I have tried to use _NavigationService.Navigated_ but it is still not working as intended. Can you please give example of how to use that? And what should be in the _NavigationService.Navigated_ method?

Answer (score 0):

Read the following page : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms615507.aspx

At the bottom after the Methods and Properties definitions in the "Remark" part it explains how the  NavigationService Class works and this nice little graphic explains a lot :

[image]